# JS/CSS to fade out and disable a block, then enable and fade in another, is fading out but popping in

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I've set up the [scenario in jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/z5vjs3oa/). My solution almost works, but it only fades out the old block, popping in the new one instead of fading in.

I've avoided the usual pitfall of trying to animate `display: none;` by transitioning the opacity first, detecting its completion, and only then setting `display: none;`. It works a charm for the fading out...

**HTML:**

```
<body>
  <p>
    Mouse over to translate:
  </p>
  <blockquote class="untranslated">
    <p>Mae govannen</p>
  </blockquote>
  <blockquote class="translated disabled fade">
    <p>Well met</p>
  </blockquote>
</body>
```

**CSS:**

```
.disabled {
  display: none;
}

.fade {
  opacity: 0 !important;
}

.untranslated,
.translated {
  opacity: 1;
  transition: opacity 0.25s;
}
```

**JS:**

```
$(function($) {

  function whichTransitionEvent() {
    var t;
    var el = document.createElement('fakeelement');
    var transitions = {
      'transition': 'transitionend',
      'OTransition': 'oTransitionEnd',
      'MozTransition': 'transitionend',
      'WebkitTransition': 'webkitTransitionEnd'
    }

    for (t in transitions) {
      if (el.style[t] !== undefined) {
        return transitions[t];
      }
    }
  }

  var transitionEnd = whichTransitionEvent();
  var untranslated = $('.untranslated');
  var translated = $('.translated');

  untranslated.bind(transitionEnd, untranslatedFaded);
  translated.bind(transitionEnd, translatedFaded);

  untranslated.mouseenter(
    function() {
      $(this).addClass('fade')
    }
  )

  translated.mouseleave(
    function() {
      $(this).addClass('fade')
    }
  )

  function untranslatedFaded() {
    untranslated.addClass('disabled'),
      translated.removeClass('disabled'),
      translated.removeClass('fade')
  }

  function translatedFaded() {
    translated.addClass('disabled'),
      untranslated.removeClass('disabled'),
      untranslated.removeClass('fade')
  }

});
```

Any ideas for getting it to fade in properly? Preferably without greatly changing the approach.

Comment: Do you rely on the css approach given for the fading? Jquery offers simple wrappers for this you could chain easily.

Comment: I would like to keep the CSS approach, unless it winds up being impossible. I want to learn how to fix my solution.

Comment: You could try fading both in and out at the same time while having the one to fade in delayed using `transition-delay: 0.25s`

Comment: Although I suggest chaining jQuery's `.fadeIn(250)` and `.fadeOut(250)` using callbacks. This would make your code much easier to understand for anyone without this explanation and reduce the amount of code by far.

Comment: I tried fixing your solution for the last 30 minutes without success. If you find the bug anyways I'd be glad to know. :)

Comment: Thanks for the attempt! I'll keep at it, too.